# how to set section heading for tables in android (ie. grouping of rows is there)

Tags: android, tablelayout

I am implementing a saxxml parser , i have successfully parsed it. But i need a feature to be implemented, there shpould be section heading which is a date say oct 26 and the rows in the section should be the feeds of that date. I have successfully implemented it in iphone, but i am very new to android and need help how to add section heading and group the rows. I am now using listview to show the feeds. Anyone has an idea abt this?
I have no idea about how to group the rows also.

Please help.

```
<day>
<date>October 19</date>
    <job>
        <value>xyz</value>
        <time>5:30</time>
    </job>
    <job>
        <value>abc</value>
        <time>6:30</time>
    </job>
```

October 20
        
            xyz
            5:30
        
        
            abc
            6:30

Comment: i can be implemented using expandable listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be implemented as an expandable list view